# Updating Data Frame after removing rows in table R

Tags: r, dataframe, assign

I am working in R Studio. I removed 2 rows at the bottom of my table with this command (I wanted to remove the rows because they had a lot of 'NA' in them and correlations were not working:

```
table[-c(52,53), ]
```

However, I cannot figure out how to update the table. The updated columns came out in the R Studio console, but the actual data frame did not update.

What is the command for that?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to assign your result to a new object, or replace your current object, e.g. `newtable <- table[-c(52,53),]` or `table <- table[-c(52,53),]`

Answer (score 1):

For updating the values, a self-assignment like `table <- table[-c(52,53), ]` is needed. Running `View(table)` should update the displayed table.

Comment: `View` just displays a table. It doesn't make any changes to it's structure whatsoever.

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood the question. For updating the values, of course, a self-assignment like  table <- table[-c(52,53), ]  is needed. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Christoph, you should add the details from our comment to the answer.

Comment: I used View(table) after using newtable <- table[-c(52,53),]. It worked!!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

In base R it is not possible to *update* data.frame. Instead you can assign new filtered data.frame to the same variable, this usually gets you what you expect. In your cases it would looks like:

```
table <- table[-c(52,53), ]
```